# How to work with files through FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOS Rest Bundle to create a REST API where I'm suppose to be able to handle file upload. The problem is I don't know how to send and receive the files. My only experience with file transfer is with $_FILES of PHP and it does not help me a lot.

I though about encoding in Base64 and sending the file in JSON but since the file can be quite large, it's not a viable solution. As of now, I'm thinking about doing a request to send the metadata with json and another request for sending the file. I did not find any example on how to handle the file transfer as it seems everyone but me knows how it works.

I'm also quite new to symfony2 but I understand the basic concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FOSRestBundle or not, you can use the `$files` provided by [Request](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) to get the file/s that was uploaded.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function uploadAction(Request $request)
{

    $file = $request->files->get('file');
    //do what ever you want to do with the files

}
```

if you want to do it using helpers offered by FOSRestBundle, check this https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/pull/1097

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this problem some months ago:

In your controller (APIController) you use this action (method)

```
public function postUploadAction(Request $request)
{   
    $uploadedfile = $this->getRequest()->files->get('file');
    $directory = __DIR__.'/../../../../web/uploads/pinkSheet';

    foreach($request->files as $uploadedFile) {
        $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());
    }

    return 'file uploaded.';
}
```

and for your client (in my case I recieved the data from an Android App), you just send the file as it would be in a html form with a key (I call mine "file") you can test it (in my case I've used the google chrom extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

Remember to choose "form-data" on postman 
I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Hi my friend... After i upload the file, can i modify it? Rename, manupulate the image?

Comment: Of course as Symfony offer some nice API to manipulate the object $uploadedFile